# Generate MATLAB code from python

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x

I have a problem when using the [MATLAB python engine](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html).

I want to get approximated solutions to ODEs (using something like the `ode45` function in MATLAB) from Python, but the problem is that ODE approximation requires an ODE function specification that I can't seem to create from the MATLAB Python engine.

It works fine calling MATLAB functions, such as `isprime`, from Python but there seems to be no way of specifying a MATLAB function in Python.

My question is therefore;
Are there any way of generating MATLAB function code from Python or is a way to specify MATLAB functions from Python?

Comment: is using scipy a possibility? `scipy.integrate.ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5')`

Comment: @JamesK It has to be MATLAB since I would like to give the user a choice of solvers/libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`odefun` passed to `ode45`, according to docs, has to be a function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html).

> Solve the ODE
>
> y' = 2t
>
> Use a time interval of [0,5] and the initial condition y0 = 0.

```
tspan = [0 5];
y0 = 0;
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0);
```

`@(t,y) 2*t` returns a function handle to anonymous function.

Unfortunately, [function handles are listed as one of datatypes unsupported in MATLAB <-> Python conversion](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/handle-data-returned-from-matlab-to-python.html):

> **Unsupported MATLAB Types The following MATLAB data types are not supported by the MATLAB Engine API for Python:**
>
> - Categorical array
> - char array (M-by-N)
> - Cell array (M-by-N)
> - **Function handle**
> - Sparse array
> - Structure array
> - Table
> - MATLAB value objects (for a discussion of handle and value classes see Comparison of Handle and Value Classes)
> - Non-MATLAB objects (such as Java® objects)

To sum up, it seems like there is no straightforward way of doing it.

Potential workaround may involve some combination of `engine.workspace` and `engine.eval`, as shown in [Use MATLAB Engine Workspace in Python](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-the-matlab-engine-workspace-in-python.html) example.

Workaround with `engine.eval` ([first demo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html)):

```
import matlab.engine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
tr, yr = e.eval('ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, [0 5], 0)', nargout=2)
plt.plot(tr, yr)
plt.show()
```

By doing so, you avoid passing function handle via MATLAB/Python barrier. You pass string (bytes) and allow MATLAB to evaluate it there. What's returned is pure numeric arrays. After that, you may operate on result vectors, e.g. plot them.

[image: Matplotlib result]

Since passing arguments as literals would quickly became pain, `engine.workspace` may be used to avoid it:

```
import matlab.engine
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

e = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
e.workspace['tspan'] = matlab.double([0.0, 5.0])
e.workspace['y0'] = 0.0
tr, yr = e.eval('ode45(@(t,y) 2*t, tspan, y0)', nargout=2)
plt.plot(tr, yr)
plt.show()
```